# Theme developer module crashes the whole site when enabled, how to fix?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm working on a clean Drupal 7.x installation, downloaded [Theme developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) and its dependent module [simplehtmldom API](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplehtmldom)( another required module for Theme developer) using drush.

I found out that simplehtmldom 7.x-2.x is incompatible; so I removed it, and  Installed  the 7.x-1.12 version using Drush, enabled it, enabled the *Theme developer* module was available to be enabled. Now the site doesn't work anymore.

All I'm seeing is just some tags like this.

```
< /> < /> < /> < /> < /> < /> < /> < /> < /> < />
```

The problem is fixed when I disable the *Theme developer* module manually with Drush; everything gets back to normal, when I disabled that module.

I've tried to navigate the site using `/node/1` and tried to go to the administration panel; all I noticed is that the title of the page (the one appearing on the browser's tab) appears but the content seems to be the same.

How do I solve this issue?

This is a screenshot.

> [image: Drupal Error devel_themer]

Comment: *This module was part of the Devel project. Now it is its own project, but relies on the Devel and simplehtmldom API modules as dependencies.* If you see the page of Theme developer module, it states that sentence. Devel module is its dependency, Now if you would have downloaded Theme developer module, Drush  would have asked you, "would you like to download dependencies, Devel and simsimplehtmldom API", Did you download Devel module also?

Comment: Yes, I have already downloaded Devel module and enabled it (Devel and Devel generate), after that I downloaded theme developer and that problem appeared.

Comment: Which theme are you using? I just repeated the process with bartik theme and there is no issue, everything works fine.

Comment: Surprisingly I'm using bartik!! I've just made a new and clean installation of drupal, I haven't downloaded or edited anything except that I've downloaded the administrator's menu module, and the devel module.

I'm doubting something here, I've downloaded drupal using a drush command "drush dl drupal-7.x", I've noticed that the drupal version downloaded was a dev version! could that be the problem?

Comment: Do one thing, remove all modules, Theme developer, simplehtmldom API and Devel module. Clear cache. Then freshly, 1. Download Devel module and enable it using drush. 2. Download simplehtmldom API-a compatible version and place manually in folder, do not enable. 3. Download Theme Developer using Drush and enable using drush, then drush will automatically ask you to enable simplehtmldom API, say `y` for both.

Comment: Okay I'll do that, is there any specific version of drupal recommended to download and install? I mean .. should I try to download another version other than the dev version? or is it okay to go on with the dev version?

Comment: Honestly, I have never used any dev version either for Drupal or for any module. For  Drupal I always use latest and stable version https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal

Comment: Okay, I'll download that 7.50 stable version and start from scratch following your steps, just consider putting your comment in an answer in case it works out well, I'll mark it as an answer then :)

Comment: @CodeNext I've just did like you said, still the same problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43272/discussion-between-codenext-and-kareem).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report to a third-party project and should be posted and discussed in its issue queue to get it fixed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report to a contrib module which must be filed on drupal.org to get it fixed not here on Drupal Answers.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to get it to work properly … eventually. This is how, on D7 7.5.

1. Download and install Theme Developer 7x. Do not enable yet.
2. Download and install SimpleHTMLDom  7.x-1.12. Do not enable yet.
3. Download SimpleHTMLDom library from
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom][1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom) and install to
   sites/all/libraries, so that your library path is
   sites/all/libraries/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php.
4. Now you can run `drush en -y devel_themer` and it will automatically
   enable the simplehtmldom.

I did notice that my /tmp folder was not giving correct permissions to the /tmp/devel_themer folder, so doing a `chmod -R` on that fixed the problem.

[image: screenshot-devel_themer enabled]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I could solve it by switching from PHP7 to PHP5.6 when using the Theme Developer (7.x-1.x-dev).